# Terraform Module Library - Monorepo vs Multirepo

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

we're currently building a library of commonly used resources in Terraform. We created a repo on Azure DevOps and dumped every resource definition into it's own folder. Like this:

```
azure-module-library
|
| - app-service-module
| - cosmosdb-module
| - key-vault-module
```

But I noticed when I reference this module library, that Terraform does a git clone of the whole repo even if I only use a single module.

- Does it make more sense to have separate repositories for each module?
- Will we get scalability issues by continuing on the current path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your 2 questions

- does it make sense to have separate repos for each module?
  This really depends on your overall goals. For example, I prefer to use 100% re-usable modules so having a separate repo for each module helped me with this goal since it's easier to re-use small modules compared to big monolithic modules.
  This discussion can help decide: https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/one-module-per-repo/13414
- will we get scalability issues by continuing on the current path?
  Current path being to grow all your modules in 1 repo... You can run into scalability issues. For example, if you need to make 1 change in 1 module from that repo, it will cause a cascading effect on any root module, where you run `terraform apply` that uses any module from that 1 module repo. So depending on how you plan on using that Module Repo will determine what kind of issues you will face when maintaining it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a real world example. We started out using 1 repo 1 module. It worked great, we could tag individually, we could do all sorts of things in CICD and all work was isolated.

However, as our infrastructure matured, the number of modules became numerous. Initializing state took a very long time. Having 50+ repos to manage became cumbersome.

I am migrating to a monorepo and our CICD pipelines, while increased a bit in complexity, the management is becoming easier overall is easier. I wrote a couple additional scripts and we are cruising.

Tagging is also pretty easy with a little governance, 1 PR should only touch 1 module. We prepend a module abbreviation to each tag for that PR.